# Can we access class from managed package in a local VF page

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, appexchange

We have a class in a managed package which is a controller for a VF page which is also a part of the managed package. Now we have a customer who wants the layout of the VF page changed to suit his needs. There is essentially not much  change except for how the layout is. I really dont want to be making changes in the managed package for this one client

I am pretty sure some of you would also have been in the same situation as we are. What is best approach to handle these type of changes in managed package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes and methods within a managed package can be accessed from outside of the managed package if they are marked global.

Another option worth considering in this case is fieldsets, which would allow the customer to control which fields appear on the VF page and order them.